# How to get text between 2 lines with PYthon

Tags: python, file-io, split

So I have a text file that is structured like this:

```
Product ID List:

ABB:
578SH8
EFC025
EFC967

CNC:
HDJ834
HSLA87
...
...
```

This file continues on with many companies' names and Id's below them. I need to then get the ID's of the chosen company and append them to a list, where they will be used to search a website. Here is the current line I have to get the data:

```
PID = open('PID.txt').read().split()
```

This works great if there are only Product ID's of only 1 company in there and no text. This does not work for what I plan on doing however... How can I have the reader read from (an example) after where it says `ABB:` to before the next company? I was thinking maybe add some kind of thing in the file like `ABB END` to know where to cut to, but I still don't know how to cut out between lines in the first place... If you could let me know, that would be great!

Comment: It doesn't have to, it was just to add a bit of convenience for the user

Comment: Remove the title line and start from the top, then try my code.

Comment: The two newlines serves as a breakpoint.

Comment: But I would only need 1 company per program ran, so I would only need ABB or CNC, not both at the same time, would that give me that?

Comment: To all the others who answered, thanks for the help. Malik's worked for what I needed to do, and he was the first to help out, even thought I'm certain all of yours would have worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two consecutive newlines act as a delimeter, so just split there an construct a dictionary of the data:

```
data = {i.split()[0]: i.split()[1:] for i in open('PID.txt').read().split('\n\n')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is structured like that you could follow these steps:

1. Split based on the two newline characters `\n\n` into a list
2. Split each list on a single newline character `\n`
3. Drop the first element for a list containing the IDs for each company
4. Use the first element (mentioned above) as needed for the company name (make sure to remove the colon)

Also, take a look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html) for parsing data like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: # open the file
    next(f) # skip the first line
    results = {} # initialize a dictionary
    for line in f: # iterate through the remainder of the file
        if ':' in line: # if the line contains a :
            current = line.strip() # strip the whitespace
            results[current] = [] # and add it as a dictionary entry
        elif line.strip(): # otherwise, and if content remains after stripping whitespace,
            results[current].append(line.strip()) # append this line to the relevant list
```

Comment: While this would work nicely, it would be good to add a couple of lines or comments to explain to the OP what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

This should at least get you started, you will likely have better luck using dictionaries than lists, at least for the first part of your logic. By what method will you pass the codes along?

```
a = {}

f1 = open("C:\sotest.txt", 'r')
current_key = ''

for row in f1:
    strrow = row.strip('\n')


    if strrow == "":
        pass
    elif ":" in strrow:
        current_key = strrow.strip(':')
        a[current_key] = []
    else:
        a[current_key].append(strrow)

for key in a:
    print key
    for item in a[key]:
        print item
```